# Playback delay when streaming <audio> in Chrome, but not in Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, stream, webkit, mp3

I'm streaming a 256 kbps mp3 in real-time for a radio-style site I'm creating. I'm streaming it over HTTP.

When I access the stream URL via Firefox, it starts playing the mp3 back immediately at the point in the song the server was streaming when it connected.

With Chrome however, it needs to buffer for at least 8 seconds before it starts playing.

How can I get Chrome (and Safari) to behave like Firefox and start playing the audio immediately?

I'm playing the audio with this code:

```
var a = new Audio('/stream');
a.play();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit older but it looks like this was a known bug with Chrome per this link:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=362387

Updated versions of Chrome should have resolved your issue for mp3 but it seems as though the issue is still a problem with other formats such as AAC.